# Azure API Management role "Service Editor"

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-rbac

In this page, there are 2 roles supposed to be provided after the migration of the old "publisher portal" to the Azure portal (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-role-based-access-control): APIM Service Editor and APIM Content Manager.

These roles are still not available (in West Europe), what is the roadmap, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The Service Editor role will be available after we migrate all the
>   admin UI from the existing publisher portal to the Azure portal. The
>   Content Manager role will be available after the publisher portal is
>   refactored to only contain functionality related to managing the
>   developer portal

There is no exact date for this. You can monitor the updates from the [Azure update website](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/?product=api-management).

[image]